# Low Accuracy On MNIST CNN with multiple GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist, multiple-gpu

Referencing to the [cifar10](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) demo for multiple GPUs, I have tried to write a multi-gpu (multi-tower fashion) code for MNIST CNN classifier. But, it is giving me a very low accuracy and no improvement in the speed as well. (Doing it on multiple GPUs is a must for me).

Appreciate any help in finding the root cause for the low accuracy. Below are the code and snapshot from the tensorboard. Thanks in advance.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np

#Make Sure it sees the devices
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print("*******Device Info Seen By TensorFlow*******")
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
print("********************************************")
#times = []

def check_available_gpus():
    local_devices = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    gpu_names = [x.name for x in local_devices if x.device_type == 'GPU']
    gpu_num = len(gpu_names)

    print('{0} GPUs are detected : {1}'.format(gpu_num, gpu_names))

    return gpu_num

def average_gradients(tower_grads):
  average_grads = []
  for grad_and_vars in zip(*tower_grads):
    # Note that each grad_and_vars looks like the following:
    #   ((grad0_gpu0, var0_gpu0), ... , (grad0_gpuN, var0_gpuN))
    grads = []
    for g, _ in grad_and_vars:
      # Add 0 dimension to the gradients to represent the tower.
      expanded_g = tf.expand_dims(g, 0)

      # Append on a 'tower' dimension which we will average over below.
      grads.append(expanded_g)

    # Average over the 'tower' dimension.
    grad = tf.concat(axis=0, values=grads)
    grad = tf.reduce_mean(grad, 0)
    # Keep in mind that the Variables are redundant because they are shared
    # across towers. So .. we will just return the first tower's pointer to
    # the Variable.
    v = grad_and_vars[0][1]
    grad_and_var = (grad, v)
    average_grads.append(grad_and_var)
    return average_grads

def conv2d(xx, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(xx, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(xx):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(xx, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


def tower_loss(cross_entropy_mean,scope):
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', cross_entropy_mean)
    losses = tf.get_collection('losses', scope)
    total_loss = tf.add_n(losses, name='total_loss')
    return total_loss

def train():
    with tf.Graph().as_default(),tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        gpu_num = check_available_gpus()
        batch_size = 150
        mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(".", one_hot=True)
        times = []
        run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

        x  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='x')
        x_img=tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
        x_dict={}
        x_dict = dict(zip(['x'+str((i)) for i in range(gpu_num)],tf.split(x_img,gpu_num)))

        y_dict={}
        y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10],  name='y')
        y_dict = dict(zip(['y'+str((i)) for i in range(gpu_num)],tf.split(y,gpu_num)))
        global_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)
        opt=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4)
        keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
        grads=[]

        w0=tf.get_variable('w0',initializer=tf.truncated_normal([5, 5,1,32], stddev=0.1),trainable=True)
        b0=tf.get_variable('b0',initializer=tf.zeros([32]),trainable=True)

        w1=tf.get_variable('w1',initializer=tf.truncated_normal([5,5,32,64], stddev=0.1),trainable=True)
        b1=tf.get_variable('b1',initializer=tf.zeros([64]),trainable=True)

        w2=tf.get_variable('w2',initializer=tf.truncated_normal([7*7*64,1024], stddev=0.1),trainable=True)
        b2=tf.get_variable('b2',initializer=tf.zeros([1024]),trainable=True)

        w3=tf.get_variable('w3',initializer=tf.truncated_normal([1024,10], stddev=0.1),trainable=True)
        b3=tf.get_variable('b3',initializer=tf.zeros([10]),trainable=True)

        with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):    
            for i in range(0,gpu_num):
                    with tf.device(('/gpu:{0}').format(i)):
                        with tf.name_scope(('scope_gpu_{0}').format(i)) as infer_scope:
                            #batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                            h_conv1=tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_dict[('x{0}').format(i)],w0)+b0);
                            h_pool1=max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

                            h_conv2=tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1,w1)+b1);
                            h_pool2=max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

                            h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])

                            h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat,w2)+b2)

                            h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
                            yy = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop,w3)+b3
                            tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
                            loss = tower_loss(tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=yy, labels=y_dict[('y{0}').format(i)])),infer_scope)
                            grads.append(opt.compute_gradients(loss,tf.trainable_variables()))
        grad = average_gradients(grads)
        apply_grad_op = opt.apply_gradients(grad,global_step=global_step)

        variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.9999, global_step)
        variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())
        # Group all updates to into a single train op.
        train_op = tf.group(apply_grad_op, variables_averages_op)

        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(yy, 1), tf.argmax(y_dict['y0'], 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), name='accuracy')
            with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
            sess.as_default()
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(),options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE),run_metadata=run_metadata)
            t1_1 = datetime.datetime.now()
            for step in range(0,5000):
                batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                start_time = time.time()
                #sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, keep_prob: 0.5})
                _, loss_val = sess.run([train_op, loss], {x: batch_x, y: batch_y, keep_prob: 0.5})
                #print(sess.run(w0))
                train_time_step = time.time() - start_time
                times.append(train_time_step)
                assert not np.isnan(loss_val), 'Model diverged with loss = NaN'
                if (step % 100) == 0:
                    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch_x, y: batch_y, keep_prob: 1.0})
                    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(step, train_accuracy))
                    #print(step, sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
                    #print(sess.run(w0))
            t2_1 = datetime.datetime.now()
            print(sess.run(w0))
            print(sess.run(w1))
            print(sess.run(w2))
            print(sess.run(w3))
            print(sess.run(b0))
            print(sess.run(b1))
            print(sess.run(b2))
            print(sess.run(b3))
            print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
            print("Total Computation time: " + str(t2_1-t1_1))
            from tensorflow.python.client import timeline
            trace = timeline.Timeline(step_stats=run_metadata.step_stats)
            trace_file = open('timeline.ctf.json', 'w')
            trace_file.write(trace.generate_chrome_trace_format())
            #Write Graph
            writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./my_graph',sess.graph)
            writer.close()
            #sess.close()
            for device in run_metadata.step_stats.dev_stats:
                                print(device.device)
                                for node in device.node_stats:
                                        print("  ", node.node_name)



    times = np.array(times)
    speeds = batch_size/times
    speed_mean = batch_size/np.mean(times)
    speed_uncertainty = np.std(speeds)/np.sqrt(float(len(speeds)))
    speed_jitter = 1.4826 * np.median(np.abs(speeds - np.median(speeds)))

    print("Mean Time Per Step : " + str(np.mean(times)))
    print("Mean Speed : " + str(speed_mean) + " Images/Sec")
    print("speed uncertainty : " + str(speed_uncertainty))
    print("Speed Jitter : " + str(speed_jitter))

def main():
    train()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[TENSORBOARD GRAH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xnJh.png)

Comment: Debugging such a long block of code remotely might be quite difficult. It might help if you provided the output though. What's the accuracy doing? Is it stuck at 1/10? Does it increase a little? Stuck below 90%?

Comment: Please see [mcve] to improve your question.

Comment: The accuracy is stuck below 60%. With 1 GPU it comes out to be around 50-60% while with 2 GPUs it's 8-15%.

Comment: Try train more than `5000` steps, it is probably not enough. 
Also it may be better to set `batch_size` to a power of 2, for example `128`

Comment: @ykaner I have tried till 20000 steps and batch_sizes of 32, 64 and 128 also with no luck.

Comment: You dividing each batch to the number of GPUs. so in case of `batch_size = 128` and 4 GPUs each of them will run on a batch of size 32. 
To fix it I would use `batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size * gpu_num)`.

Comment: if the 20000 size gives any little improvement, try to do 200000.

Comment: @ykaner Tried both of your suggestions, the accuracy is still low (~10% on 2 GPUs). When I saw the final weights and biases, I can see that all the biases are coming out to be zero. My guess is that it is failing to update the Weights and Biases or with each iteration, it somehow resets them and starts from the initial value (random/zeros). Any thoughts on that? Appreciate your response.

Comment: I think is better to initialize the biases and the weights using `truncated_normal_initializer`. 
(p.s. check the 'Edit' in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed. The problem was with aggregation of accuracy, correct predictions, and gradients due to which the update variable operation was not updating all the variables properly and was also not calculating the accuracy properly. Upon fixing these issues I'm able to get a good accuracy (>99% on the test data) and also I'm able to use multiple GPUs. Thanks a lot everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if the issue is not related to the numerical errors. `float32` is rather limited in its accuracy and aggregating the results from so many GPUs can introduce errors that make the model not converging (particularly that you perform quite a number of array operations that are accumulating errors - e.g. averaging).
To confirm this hypothesis you could run the code with 1, 2, 4, 8 GPUs and see if the accuracy diminishes with the number of GPUs. If it does then numerical errors are likely to be blamed. Increasing the accuracy and checking if that changes the end result may also be a good test.

Comment: With 1 GPU it comes out to be around 50-60% while with 2 GPUs it's 8-15%. I'll also try 4 and beyond. But, before trying the above code I have tried the same CNN without the multi-tower fashion and with the same type of variables (float32) (which runs on the default/1st GPU) and I got an accuracy of >97%.

Also, can you please elaborate on the last statement `Increasing the accuracy and checking if that changes the end result may also be a good test`?

Comment: He meant increasing the accuracy of the float variables e.g. use tf.float64. (in my opinion this is not your issue)

Comment: Got it and I agree since now it's giving almost similar accuracy with both 1 and 2 GPUs. But the accuracy for me is still stuck ~60%. Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I take a look on your code and saw that you defining the `w0, b0 ... w3, b3` using `tf.get_variable` but independent from the loop over GPUs.

Try defining the variables **inside** the `with tf.variable_scope(('scope_gpu_{0}').format(i))` scope. 
Since you using `tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()` all the variables will be shared between the towers (although it seems you defining them in a loop for each of the towers).

**Edit:**

Look at this line:

`correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(yy, 1), tf.argmax(y_dict['y0'], 1))`

Here `yy` is the last logits from the loop over GPUs, contains the prediction from the **last** GPU. But `y_dict['y0']` is the **first** GPU labels. 
To fix it you should make a list of `correct_prediction`s like you did gradients and then average it.

Comment: I have tried that with similar results, and that's one of the reasons why I moved all the weights and biases to CPU suspecting they might not be updating properly (with no luck of course).

Comment: I have tried your suggestion in 'Edit' by adding the line `correct_predictions.append(tf.equal(tf.argmax(yy, 1), tf.argmax(y_dict[('y{0}').format(i)],1)))` in the GPU loop and taking accuracy as `accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, tf.float32), name='accuracy')` outside the GPU loop. Did I implement your suggestion correctly? Continued...

Comment: ... The good news is it increased the accuracy now to ~50-60% with both 1GPU and 2 GPUs also I can see the speed improvement with 2 GPUs compared to 1 GPU (not sure how it helped improve the speed scaling). But the bad news is the accuracy still hasn't reached the expectations (>90%) and I can still see the biases in the end as zeros (when I print it with `sess.run(b0)`). Any suggestions?